# Changing colour of pop-up coc.nvim lint warning in custom colourscheme

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, plugin-coc

I'm using the `colorscheme` [monokai](https://github.com/sickill/vim-monokai) and [coc.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) with pylint to lint Python code in Vim (terminal, not GUI, in terminal.app on macOS which I'm pretty sure has 256 colours). The linting pops up on a black background, so errors (red) are basically readable, but hints (blue) are very difficult to read:

[image]

Looking at the colorscheme, I wasn't able to figure out which value to change to get a different coloured background for these messages. For instance I would guess that one of these would be relevant:

```
hi ErrorMsg ctermfg=231 ctermbg=197 cterm=NONE guifg=#f8f8f0 guibg=#f92672 gui=NONE
hi WarningMsg ctermfg=231 ctermbg=197 cterm=NONE guifg=#f8f8f0 guibg=#f92672 gui=NONE
```

But 231 per [this website](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/) is white, so that doesn't seem to be the right line. Are there some defaults it might be inheriting?

*Additional info*: this [really nifty tip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1470179/6220759) shows a way to echo information about the highlight group under the cursor in normal mode, including name and colour. However it doesn't for the pop-up box that coc uses to show lint messages, so I'm still unsure.

Comment: Interim solution: switching to this [alternative monokai theme](https://github.com/crusoexia/vim-monokai).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer via [this Reddit commenter](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/eh9eos/which_coc_colors_are_being_used_here/fchiiq4/): these floating boxes are controlled by coc itself.

- In this case the box is called `CocHintFloat` and can be seen with `:hi CocHintFloat`.
- In general `:hi Co<tab>` shows you all the possible coc highlight groups.
- To change it, add eg `highlight CocHintFloat ctermfg=Red  guifg=#ff0000` to your `.vimrc`.
- The background colour is the regular `Pmenu` specified in most colour schemes.

Comment: If CoC is using the new (introduced between 8.1 and 8.2) Vim popups then you should be able to change the background with Popup, too. (Thus not changing PMenu which is used in places other than standard popups.)

Comment: Thanks for the tip! As far as I can tell it doesn't, though.

Comment: Ah, okay. Well it's a tip that will be come more useful with time as Vim's popups get wider adoption. :) Cheers.

Comment: For the floating popup I was getting, `CocHintFloat` didn't work for me, but `CocFloating` and `CocErrorFloat` did. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64293783/629530. Maybe I was facing a different popup with my error? Just thought I'd share this in case this helped someone else.